# How to create login api without registration api in laravel passport but creation of token and storing it in database should be there in login api

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I have created the rest api which will compare username and password with the database. I want to add passport authentication to add security   to my api's. But I am not registering any user. My api is read api , but  I want to generate token and save it in row where username and password matches in database.

```
if(!empty($username))
    {
        if(!empty($password))
        {

            $isUserExist = Orders::where('username',$username)->where('password',$password)->where('status','!=',7)->exists();


             if($isUserExist)
             {
                $response = ['status' => 'success', 'Response' => 'true', 'statusCode' => Response::HTTP_OK];

                //here I want to replace User model with my Order model 
                // also save the token where username=$username, password=$password, status!=7

                $input = $request->all(); 
                $user = User::create($input); 
                $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;

                $user['remember_token'] = $success['token'];
                $user->save();

                return response()->json(['response'=> $response]);
             }
             else
             {
                $response = ['status' => 'failed', 'Response' => 'false','statusCode' => Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST];
                return response()->json(['response'=> $response]);
             }
        }
        else
         {
            $response = ['status' => 'failed', 'Response' => 'password not found','statusCode' => Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST];
                return response()->json(['response'=> $response]);
         }
     }
    else
     {
        $response = ['status' => 'failed', 'Response' => 'username not found','statusCode' => Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST];
                return response()->json(['response'=> $response]);
     }

    }
```

when authenticated user login is successful response is generated , should generate token and store it to database

Comment: I believe what you want is a password grant token.  This is outlined in the Laravel documentation. 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#password-grant-tokens

Comment: share your code snippet to get attention.

Comment: @matticustard My api's don't require any view files , i am using only controllers and models

Comment: How are you creating your users? Authenticating a user requires at least one user.

Comment: @adam users are already in the database in my api is read api which will check username and password is correct or not but i want to generate token and store to the database if authenticated user logged in.

Comment: @Mihir passport does this for you already.

Comment: $user=Orders::where('username',$username)->where('password',$password)->where('status','!=',7)->first();
                    
$token=$user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
$user['remember_token']=$token;
$user->save(); It is solved now :)